# problem book on Differential calculus of two real variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

i require problem book on:

1. Differential calculus of two real variable: containing problems on limit,continuity and differentiability of functions of two variables.

in this connection, i have seen book like [Problems in Nathematical Analysis by Demidovich](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007BNL1W). but this book lacks problems on differentiablility and continuity, maxima minima of functions of two variables.

please add your suggestions in this regard. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can look at Problems in Analysis by Kaczor & Novak by AMS. But these questions are hard. You probably want to read the ordinary books on analysis first like Apostol's or Ken Ross's intro to analysis before you do the hard questions on those books.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=STML-12 does not contain function of two variables. which one do you mention?

Comment: it doesnot have multivariable differential calculus